# How to include / copy over the `src` directory when building Emacs

Tags: emacs

I would like to be able to use `find-function` and `find-variable` for definitions found within the `src` directory and am wondering whether it is possible to have this packaged into the application when building, rather than coping this over manually after the Emacs build has already occurred.  I'm building on `OSX` with the following command-line entries:

```
/macports/bin/bzr branch --stacked bzr://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/emacs/trunk emacs-trunk

;; cd over to the new emacs-trunk directory that was just downloaded.

/macports/bin/bzr pull

./autogen.sh

./configure --with-ns

make bootstrap

make && make install

;; the new Emacs build is waiting for you in .../emacs-trunk/nextstep
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to do it manually:

```
M-x eshell

/macports/bin/bzr branch --stacked bzr://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/emacs/trunk emacs-trunk

;; cd over to the newly downloaded '.../emacs-trunk' main directory

/macports/bin/bzr pull

./autogen.sh

./configure --with-ns

make bootstrap

make && make install

cp -r /Users/HOME/Desktop/emacs-trunk/src /Users/HOME/Desktop/emacs-trunk/nextstep/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/

;; create:  '.../lisp/site-start.el' with the following contents:

(load-file "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/init.el")

;; adjust the following c-source variable as needed:

(setq find-function-C-source-directory (concat root.d "Emacs_01_19_2014.app/Contents/Resources/src"))
```